How to populate 1st row of existing column into new column of 2nd row
I want to get the value of "Beg of year" column for 2015 from the column "Open at the end" and Year 2014, same as shown in below snapshot



Year
Beg of year
Report in year
Close
Total Inven
Open at the end




2014
0
94
0
94
94


2015
94
102
12
196
184


2016
184
49
42
233
191


2017
191
49
51
240
189


2018
189
62
25
251
226


2019
226
51
27
277
250


2020
250
29
34
279
245


2021
245
16
21
261
240


2022
240
21
16
261
240


2023
245
8
25
253
228


2024
228
481
2
709
707



Note: Column Total Inven = Beg of year + report in year
  Column open at the end = Total inven - Close


Open at the begining of Cal year = MAXX(
FILTER(
ALLSELECTED('Claims Data (2)'),'Claims Data (2)'[Year]='Claims Data (2)'[Calender year]),[Open at the end])

This give the following error because column "Open at the end" is calculated from :
Total inven = Beg of year + report in year


A circular dependency was detected: Measure: 'Claims Data (2)'[Total
Inventory], Measure: 'Claims Data (2)'[Open at the beg], Measure:
'Claims Data (2)'[Open at the end], Measure: 'Claims Data (2)'[Total
Inven]


Can you clarify what you want to achieve?

@AmiraBedhiafi I want the 1st row value of column "Open at the end" in 2nd row of column "Beg of year" and should be in similar pattern for row 3,4,5... (Please see the table above)

you can try this
Column =
SUMX (
    FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Year] <= EARLIER ( 'Table'[Year] ) ),
    'Table'[Report in year] - 'Table'[Close]
)


beg of year2 = maxx(FILTER('Table','Table'[Year]=EARLIER('Table'[Year])-1),'Table'[Column])+0



getting below error
EARLIER/EARLIEST refers to an earlier row context which doesn't exist.

and this is my final column "Open at end", Now I want the first column  2nd rpw (Beg of year, year 2015)= (Open at End, year 2014)

what are the columns that in your raw data? i have updated my answer, pls have a try.
